# Paypal clientId, ClientSecret, username, password, signature

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I can see some of the paypal payments have done using the paypal clientId, ClientSecret while other type of payments normally nvp payments is doing the payments using username, password and signature. What is the difference between payments using client Id and secret and using username, password and signature. Please explain this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general,

Client ID + Secret = REST API transactions, retrieve the credentials through https://developer.paypal.com

API username + API password + Signature = Classic API transactions, retrieve the credentials through https://paypal.com

More information on the API credentials:

- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/ (Classic API)
- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/paypal-oauth2/ (REST API)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Also one more added question on this is, is it possible to storer credit card details using this classic api of paypal. I can only see the store credit card functionality using this REST API only.

Comment: It is not exactly credit card storage feature, but it can done through reference transaction and use initial payment transaction id as token. You can refer here for its implementation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/direct-payment/ht_dp-referenceTransactions-curl-etc/

Comment: This is only returns a transaction id, but in my application i have to do the recurring payment now and for recurring payment i need to store the credit card details either in local database or in paypal server itself. But the storing in local database in not PCI complaince. Also i have already implement the DoDirectPayment on my application. That's why i am checking an option for storing credit card on DodirectPayment option. I need to show the last four digit of the credit card on the form and also expiry date, users just needs to enter cvv number and do the transaction.